# Writing a group $G$ as a product $HN$,where $H$ is a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.Moreover,$P$ be a sylow subgroup of $H$.

I have to show that,

i) $\forall g\in G\  \  \exists h\in H $ such that $gPg^{-1}=hPh^{-1}$

ii)Let $N=\{g\in G|gPg^{-1}=P\}$.And $HN$ is defined as usual by $HN=\{hn|h\in H;n\in N \}$.Prove that $G=HN.$

My attempt:  I can do the first part as follows.

$\because H\trianglelefteq G$     $\therefore$ $gPg^{-1}\subseteq H$,So $P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ both are sylow subgroups inside $H$.($\because |P|=|gPg^{-1}$).And we know that any two sylow subgroups inside a group are conjugate.Therefore,i can get a $h\in H$ such that $gPg^{-1}=hPh^{-1}$

But i am having a bit of problem to show the second part.What would a conceptual solution to that one(without involving large computations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuition / skeleton solution:

Clearly $HN\le G$, so you need to show $G\le HN$.

So, let $g\in G$. You need $g=hn$ for some $h\in H$ and $n\in N$.

You can use the first part to obtain an interesting $h$ and you would need $n=h^{-1}g$, so you'd need to show $h^{-1}g\in N$.

Comment: You have just rephrased the question!!  @Chamberlain

Comment: @SoumyadipSarkar  For $g \in G, \exists h \in H$ such that $gPg^-=hPh^- \Rightarrow (h^-g)P(h^-g)^-=P \Rightarrow h^-g \in N$ and so $g=h(h^-g) \in HN$ .